# My method can't find files in directory

Tags: java, io

```
public class Cww {
static List<String> readFile(String filename) {
    List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            records.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        return records;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

and my main:

```
readFile("DirList.java");

    File file = new File("DirList.java");
    System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());

// CLASSPATH: .;..;J:\Programowanie\eclipse workspace\tij;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\QTJava.zip

output: java.io.FileNotFoundException: DirList.java (Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku)
J:\Programowanie\eclipse workspace\Rozdzial 18 cwiczenia\DirList.java
```

`file.getCanonicalPath()` shows that jvm search for my file where it really is, but my `fileRead` method is still giving me error,

Do I need to include every project folder in my classpath to read files from them ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: classpath  is only used to tell the Java Virtual Machine or the compiler where to look for user-defined classes and packages.It has nothing to do with your file. Add file to your workspace or give a absolute path to your file.

Comment: Are these files application resources (help HTML, button icons etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

The `File` constructor argument is an absolute or relative filename. It will not use the classpath, the filename is - if not absolute - always relative to the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

`FileReader(filename)` will open a "DirList.java" in the directory from where your java code was executed (relative path). It is not related to the CLASSPATH in any way.